# Hiding status bar on one of tabs does leave a black rectangle

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, hidden, statusbar

I have a UITabBarController-based application and its deployment target is iOS5.1 (so, I am not using View controller-based status bar appearance feature of iOS7). And I want to hide the status bar on the first tab. It works fine on the first launch (the view is stretched to take 431 points = 480 - 49 points of tabBar), but after changing tab and coming back to the first screen, the status bar is hidden, but there is a black rectangle on top.

My code (AppDelegate + the first tab ViewController):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
    return YES;
}

- (void) loadView {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    NSLog(@"load View %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}  

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
    ...
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view willAppear %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
    ....
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view didAppear %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
    ....
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    ....
    self.view = nil;
}
```

And here is the trace output:

load View {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

view did load {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

view willAppear {{0, 0}, {320, 431}}

view didAppear {{0, 0}, {320, 431}}

load View {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

view did load {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

view willAppear {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}

view didAppear {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}

As it is seen in the log, status bar height is subtracted from the view height in `viewWillAppear:` method, when it is triggered for the second time on coming back to the first tab screen. Why does it happen?
Any advice how to fix/bypass that will be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I've already tried to insert `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` into all view-callbacks (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc), but it did not help! Also I've tried the following tricks with no luck:
1) show/dismiss a dummy modal view controller after hiding the status bar;
2) `[self.view sizeToFit];` + `[self.view setNeedsLayout];`